# SignalR - in production, after 8 hours doesn't respond

Tags: signalr, self-hosting

using SignalR in procution. at startup everything works fine, but after 8-9 hours, service stops working, without any exception, or any log information in Event Logs.

**Info:**

- Online Users (who uses this service in this 8-9 hours): 3000
- Online Concurrent Users Max (at same time): 200
- Hubs Count: 1 (try catch in every method for logging)

after browser timeout, it returns "404 not found".

do u have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of SignalR are you using?  You should be using v0.5.2 as previous versions had issues with zombie connections which would shut down your app by causing either an `OutOfMemoryException` or exceed the allowed number of requests for the app pool.

Essentially what would happen is that the # of requests would get backed up (use the performance monitor to view ASP.NET/{Requests Current, Requests Queued, Requests Rejected} - [See Performance Tuning](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Performance)) and/or you would max out your IIS requests and the service would shut down.  You can manually override this and increase your Requests Current for ASP.NET.  I increased this to about 20,000 on our production box.

If you're not maxing out your requests, your app pool may be shutting down due to increased memory usage or # of exceptions shutting down the app pool.

In the IIS manager, under Management, double-click on Configuration Editor.

[image]

Next, at the top, click on `system.applicationHost/applicationPools` then click on the RHS of the line that says "(Collection)".  This will open up your application pool collection editor.

[image]

Select your SignalR app pool and check the Properties at the bottom.  Here you can set the `periodicRestart/memory` threshold to whatever you want.

[image]

In our application I'm finding that we're good for about 45 minutes, due to the high traffic nature of the application.

Hopefully that helps.